# How to check if my visualforce publisher action is running on Salesforce1 or on the web

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, publisher

I want to know if there is a way to detect if my Visualforce page which implements a custom publisher action, is running inside Salesforce1 or inside a desktop browser.

I need this since when I run my visualforce on Salesforce1 it is framed automatically by a "Cancel" and "Submit" button, however when running on the desktop I get none of these buttons so I need to add a specific button to actually save the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that :

```
 if( (typeof sforce.one != 'undefined') && (sforce.one != null) ) 
{
   alert("This is Salesforce1");    
}
else
{
   alert("This is Salesforce Desktop");
}
```

Comment: Spot on @brovasi thanks!!!, I changed the if to just "if( (typeof sforce != 'undefined') && (sforce.one != null) )" since I was getting an undefined error on sforce object

Comment: Oh yeah I wasn't sure if it was "sforce" or "sforce.one", cheers man